# Import JPOS (gradle) in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jpos

I downloaded the jpos-template and ran the gradlew.bat, gradele inatallapp which gives me the following folder structure:

```
|-- COPYRIGHT                                                             
|-- CREDITS 
|-- LICENSE
|-- README.md                                                             
|-- build.gradle                                                          
|-- settings.gradle                                                       ... ...
|-- gradlew                                                             
  |-- gradlew.bat 
|-- gradle 
|       `-- wrapper 
|       |-- gradle-wrapper.jar 
|        `-- gradle-wrapper.properties ... ...
|-- jpos                                                                 
 |   |-- build.gradle 
|     |-- src |   |
    |-- main |  
|-- java |   |  
    |-- main |   
   |-- resources
|     |-- dist                                                          
  |-- bin 
 |-- bsh 
|-- q2 
|-- start 
 |   `-- stop 
|-- cfg 
|-- packager 
|-- base1.xml 
|-- base24-eps.xml 
|-- base24.xml 
|-- deploy 
|-- 00_logger.xml 
|   `-- 99_sysmon.xml 
|   `-- log 
|       `-- q2.log ... ...
```

How do i import this project into netbeans?
I tried importing it

**i keep getting an error "Package folder already used in project"**

Comment: You could install the gradle plugin in NetBeans, then you should be able to open the project directoy. Otherwise you need to create a new "project with existing source" and specify the location of the source directory correctly and the needed libraries

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i have installed gradle in netbeans, please how do i go about it?

Answer (score 0):

restart the IDE and Go to File-Open Project and point to your jposTemplate Project

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7M9g.jpg)